# Places a 2dimensional array position in a stack

Tags: java

So I am confused on how to implement a 2 dimensional array into a stack. What I am trying to do is store the position of a 2d array and place each position into a stack. The array is of type char but I want to get both the index position and what is side of the element. Is that possible to do in java. I cannot find a solution to this problem anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Post the code you've written so far and you'll get better assistance.

Comment: You can have a stack of `Map` where a map is `Map<Pair<x,y>,Char>`.  Alternatively you can have a stack of `Pair<x,y>` and use it values (x,y) to retrieve `array[x][y]`.